# setTimeout delay of ~100ms when set to 0

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api, p5.js

As a personnal project I'm trying to reproduce a piano roll (like the ones in DAWs) using p5.js, Web Midi Api and Web Audio Font.
When implementing the play function, I first did it with a while loop, but I realised that I couldn't stop the track from playing since javascript is single thread. So I tried to play the notes recursively with this code :

```
function playTrackRecursively(id) {
  var delay = 0;
  isTrackPlaying = true;
  playNote(mainTrack[id][0], 0);
  if (id < mainTrack.length - 1 && isTrackPlaying){
    delay = mainTrack[id + 1][1] - mainTrack[id][1];
    recursiveID = setTimeout(function() {
      playTrackRecursively(id + 1);
    }, delay * 1000);
  }
  isTrackPlaying = false;
}
```

It's working fine except that when I try to play multiple notes simultaneously, they play each one after the other with a delay of roughly 100ms.

What could I do ?
Thank you.

Comment: It's the nature of how [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#Late_timeouts) works. "This is because even though setTimeout was called with a delay of zero, it's placed on a queue and scheduled to run at the next opportunity; not immediately. Currently-executing code must complete before functions on the queue are executed, thus the resulting execution order may not be as expected."

Comment: You yourself noted that Javascript is single threaded - so how did you expect it to be able to do two of your timeout functions at the same time?

Comment: I kindly suggest you to use a library like HowlerJS. You'll really hardly align multiple audio sources to play as seamless. Or most likely your codebase will get pretty huge by trying to achieve exactly what a library already handles and solves out of the box.

Comment: @fredrik because in my first solution with the while loop, the sound are not playing simultaneously but with a very low delay so to a human ear we get the illusion that they're playing at the same time.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I might be wrong but I don't think Howler.js handles generating midi sounds like Web Midi Api.

Comment: @MoniqueDumont ugh I apologize, I missed the MIDI part somehow.

Comment: Add code to batch playSound calls (with no delay between them) in a iterative loop (avoiding recursive call to setTimeout), so they stay in the same event loop.

Comment: @user120242 That's what I first did, and it worked but as I said I need to implement a pause and stop functionnalities, and since it's single threaded I can't interact with the iterative loop once it's started. Also the guy who wrote Web Audio Font did himself a piano roll, and from looking at the 3000 lines of codes, I saw that he was doing it recursively so I know that it's doable somehow.

Or maybe I didn't get what you mean, in that case I'm sorry !

Comment: Do you have a source we can look at for that?  Have you looked at using one of the midi api wrapping libraries that allow chainable wait syntax or specific timing and whatever?  I don't think I've seen a simple API for syncing frames and sound that was trivial to implement and without a good library of some sort.

Comment: @user120242 Sure I have it : https://surikov.github.io/RiffShareAndroid/app/src/main/assets/RiffShareFlat.js I'm talking about the function queueNextBeats at line 1068. 
If you also want to take a look at his app : https://surikov.github.io/RiffShareAndroid/app/src/main/assets/index.html

Comment: I'll check back when I'm totally sure, but a quick scan seems to indicate that beats under a certain delay threshhold are actually sent in a batch in the while loop `while (this.sentWhen < t + beat16duration) {
   this.sendNextBeats(this.nextWhen, this.nextBeat, this.nextBeat);`  also looks like he has special handling for it, so I'm guessing it's a tricky problem to deal with

Comment: @user120242 Ok I think I get what you mean, I'm going to investigate it. Thanks !

Comment: @user120242 You were right ! I just play every note that need to start at the same time in a for loop, and I do it recursively through the track. It's working perfectly now, thanks again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution with the help of @user120242 in the comments.

So it was just a mix between the two solutions that I had.
I go recursively through every timestamp in the track, and each time I get all the notes that start here in an array, then I play them one by one (it's fast enough to give the illusion of simultaneity). So despite what I read, it was indeed possible.

Here is the code :

```
function playTrackRecursively(id) {
  var delay = 0;
  isTrackPlaying = true;
  var notesBatch = getNotesOfSameStartTime(mainTrack[id][1]);
  playNotesInBatch(notesBatch);
  if (id + notesBatch.length < mainTrack.length && isTrackPlaying){
    delay = mainTrack[id + notesBatch.length][1] - mainTrack[id][1];
    recursiveID = setTimeout(function() {
      playTrackRecursively(id + notesBatch.length);
    }, delay * 1000);
  }
}

function playNotesInBatch(notes) {
  for (var i = 0; i < notes.length; i++) {
    playNote(notes[i][0], notes[i][1]);
  }
}

function getNotesOfSameStartTime(startTime) {
  var indexArray = []
  for (var i = 0; i < mainTrack.length; i++) {
    if (mainTrack[i][1] == startTime) {
      indexArray.push(i);
    }
  }
  var batch = mainTrack.slice(indexArray[0], indexArray[indexArray.length - 1] + 1);
  return batch;
}
```

Comment: Just an explanation for future visitors who want to know why this works.  By batching calls and avoiding the setTimeout, you keep the playSound calls in the same event loop (and in the same loop), so that the calls don't have to wait at the end of the queue (after current code finishes executing) to execute.

Comment: Also you can accept your own answer as a solution to give the question closure

Comment: @user120242 will do. Thanks!